# CloudFlare changes WebApi user friendly ResponseText/StatusCode/ReasonPhrase from Web API V2 server

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, cloudflare

Using Web API V2, hosted as an Azure Web App with CloudFlare switched on the ReasonPhrase (a.k.a StatusText, ResponseText) is not returned to the client.

The ReasonPhrase is set in a ExceptionFilterAttribute like this:

```
public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
{
        //...code removed for brevity

        var ex = context.Exception;
        context.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(ex.StatusCode)
        {
            ReasonPhrase = GetUserFriendlyMessage(ex),
        };
}
```

This works locally, and when CloudFlare is bypassed. But not when CloudFlare is active.

Why would CloudFlare strip this out, and how can it be disabled or should user friendly API error messages be handled differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By moving the user friendly error message to the body of the request, instead of the reasonPhrase, I was able to work around this issue. Presumably CloudFlare or Azure don't like a longer ReasonPhrase...

New OnException method:

```
public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
{
    //...code removed for brevity

    var ex = context.Exception;
    context.Response = request.CreateResponse(ex.StatusCode, new
    {
       message = friendlyMessage,
    });
}
```